# What is the best way of conditionally rendering certain content in Swift

Tags: swift

I am building an app which has a dashboard, and have built it in my main storyboard.

Currently, this dashboard renders the same view - no matter whether there is any content to display or not.

As a result, what I want to do is render this screen if there is data that is associated with the user's account which would be shown on screen. However, if there isn't data - I want to display a 'no data found' screen which has an image and a button to add data.

This second 'no data' screen isn't in my main storyboard, and I don't think the right way to do it is to redirect a user depending upon the result of the query.

In React, this is really straightforward - you can use ternary operators to display certain components based upon a condition.

What is the most efficient and effective way for me to do this in Swift? Would I have to programmatically build the screen for this to work as expected?

Comment: Swift on which platform, using which UI toolkit?

Comment: Just standard swift. I think by UI Toolkit you’re meaning UI Kit, which I’m also using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, UIViews are the equivalent of Components in React. If you're using storyboard, you have an initial Root View Controller. This is probably where you placed all your views. You have multiple options here if you wanted a dynamic display depending on some data/condition, most of logic here would be handled in code.

1. Create View A and View B on the same root view controller, and create references to those constraints in the storyboard. In your code, turn hide/show view A and view B depending on your conditions (set the isHidden property). You will also need to turn off and on certain constraints as well.
2. Create View A and View B from a IBDesignable XIB file. Then, in your code, either add View A or View B to the view hierarchy on the root view controller depending on your conditions.
3. Create View A on your root view controller. Create View B an other view controller. This means having 2 view controllers in your storyboard. Upon load, check your conditions. If you need View A, do nothing. If you need View B, remove View A from hierarchy and add View B's View Controller as a child view on top of the root view controller like this:

```
let vcB = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
let viewB = vcB.view
self.view.addSubview(viewB)
self.addChild(vcB)
vcB.didMove(toParent: self)
```